# Vim search replace to end of code block

Tags: search, vim, replace

I'd like to search and replace to the end of the code block I'm in.

Essentially I want to search over the motion `]}`.

I tried

```
:]}s/=/+=/gc
```

and it didn't work. "Parse error"

I'm working with VsVIM in Visual Studio if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:` ranges do not take motion arguments.  You could do this via visual mode:

<kbd>v</kbd><kbd>]}</kbd><kbd>:s/=/+=/gc</kbd>

Note that when you hit <kbd>:</kbd> in visual mode, it will embed the ranges for you.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for in the least keystrokes.  Thanks. I forgot about doing it with visual mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the block with 

`{
Shift-v 
}`

then make:

```
:s/src/dst/g
```

Comment: This actually selects a paragraph (which means it goes from a blank line to a blank line) instead of just to the end of the code block but it's useful anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that will work in VsVim but you could do something like this in Vim:

```
[{v]}:s/=/+=/gc
```

Note that you can use a numeric range too:

```
:56,75s/=/+=/gc
```

Comment: Both useful and really close to what I was aiming at.

Answer (score 1):

As hepta said, you could do visual mode then your replace.

You could also do `:.,.5s/old/new/gc`

Or  `:.,/}/-1s/old/new/gc`

See [vim.wikia.com/wiki/Ranges](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Ranges)

Comment: First method works, second doesn't in VsVIM.  I tried it in VIM and it does... Bug maybe